# Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter name failed on Package[ntp]:

Tags: puppet, ntp

I am getting the following error while running puppet:

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter name failed on Package[ntp]: Name must be a String not Array at /etc/puppet/modules/ntp/manifests/install.pp:4

```
$ cat install.pp 
class ntp::install inherits ntp {

  package { 'ntp':
    ensure => $package_ensure,
    name   => $package_name,
  }
```

On the puppet master I have installed ntp, and wonder if that is causing a conflict.

I installed with commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install ntp
```

and config

```
$ cat /etc/ntp.conf
server 0.us.pool.ntp.org
server 1.us.pool.ntp.org
server 2.us.pool.ntp.org
server 3.us.pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple syntax error in your manifest; something is setting `$package_ensure` to an array, when `ensure` wants it to be a string.  Fix the definition of `$package_ensure`, and you're golden.